# Custom get_the_password_form

Tags: categories, password, private

I'm interested in creating a filter for pages with password protection and that have a certain category. I've placed this code in my theme's child folder in functions.php since I didn't want to edit the wp-includes files.

```
/**
 * Retrieve v1-i1 protected post password form content.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param int|WP_Post $post Optional. Post ID or WP_Post object. Default is global $post.
 * @return string HTML content for password form for password protected post.
 */
function get_the_v1i1_password_form( $post = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post( $post );
    $label = 'pwbox-' . ( empty($post->ID) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $output = '<form action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '" class="post-password-form" method="post">
    <p>' . __( 'This is exclusive content from v1:i1. Please enter password below:' ) . '</p>
    <p><label for="' . $label . '">' . __( 'Password:' ) . ' <input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" /></label> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr_x( 'Enter', 'post password form' ) . '" /></p></form>
    ';

    /**
     * Filters the HTML output for the protected post password form.
     *
     * If modifying the password field, please note that the core database schema
     * limits the password field to 20 characters regardless of the value of the
     * size attribute in the form input.
     *
     * @since 2.7.0
     *
     * @param string $output The password form HTML output.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'the_password_form', $output );
}


// If post password required and it doesn't match the cookie.
    if (post_password_required( $post ) && in_category( 'v1-i1' )) {
    return get_the_v1i1_password_form( $post );
} else {
    return get_the_password_form( $post );
}
    `
```

I can't seem to get this to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is not working? `get_the_special_password_form()` is not being called? Or is it not returning any output? Are those code in a Page template (e.g. `page.php`)?

Comment: I get a blank/error page stating that the page cannot be loaded. `get_the_special_password_form()` is being called, however, I think I might need to add an else statement so that it reverts to the standard password form if no category is found.

Comment: You shouldn't call `post_password_required()` or run that if block directly from the functions.php file like that. Try moving it to (an appropriate place in) a *single Post* template, e.g. the `single.php` file. Or you could hook to `the_content` and run the `if` from there.

Comment: I added it all to the `single.php` file and placed it in the child folder of the theme. I'm still not having any luck. I'm not sure I fully understand "an appropriate place"

The page can be viewed here: [link](https://fwwd.design/v1-i1/)
The text should read: This is exclusive content from v1:i1. Please enter password below:

The page has been given the category "v1-i1"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really get what you wanted to do.. so remove that - "*I added it all to the single.php file*" and check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/#source) of the `get_the_content()` function which retrieves the post content, you'd see the following conditional:

```
if ( post_password_required( $post ) )
    return get_the_password_form( $post );
```

And in the `get_the_password_form()` function, there's a filter you can use to customize the HTML of the default password form:

```
return apply_filters( 'the_password_form', $output );
```

So based on your code, this is how it should be, and be placed in the theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function get_the_v1i1_password_form( $output ) {
    // If not in the v1-i1 category, return the $output as-is.
    if ( ! in_category( 'v1-i1' ) ) {
        return $output;
    }

    // Here you can customize the form HTML.
    $post = get_post();
    $label = 'pwbox-' . ( empty($post->ID) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $output = '<form action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '" class="post-password-form" method="post">
    <p>' . __( 'This is exclusive content from v1:i1. Please enter password below:' ) . '</p>
    <p><label for="' . $label . '">' . __( 'Password:' ) . ' <input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" /></label> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr_x( 'Enter', 'post password form' ) . '" /></p></form>
    ';

    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'get_the_v1i1_password_form' );
```

Note: The `get_the_v1i1_password_form()` is now a filter callback, so you shouldn't use the `return apply_filters( 'the_password_form', $output );` which would cause the page to *stop working*.

And you also don't need this:

```
if (post_password_required( $post ) && in_category( 'v1-i1' )) {
    return get_the_v1i1_password_form( $post );
} else {
    return get_the_password_form( $post );
}
```

### Additional Note

The above code gives you full control over the form HTML, but if all you want to do is replace the text "`This content is password protected. To view it please enter your password below:`", then you can simply use `str_replace()` like so:

```
function get_the_v1i1_password_form( $output ) {
    // If is in the v1-i1 category, replace the text.
    if ( in_category( 'v1-i1' ) ) {
        return str_replace(
            'This content is password protected. To view it please enter your password below:',
            'This is exclusive content from v1:i1. Please enter password below:',
            $output
        );
    }

    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'get_the_v1i1_password_form' );
```

But of course, that would only work with the default output of the `get_the_password_form()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the revised answer Sally - that did the trick. I will be customizing the HTML, but it is good to know that there is a simply way of replacing the text string. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the function `get_the_special_password_form` Please return output from the above function and also contact the $label to $output before return the value if you also want the label.

Comment: I am calling the function `get_the_special_password_form` in `functions.php`

Comment: Please call the function of       'get_the_special_password_form'           from the single.php because I am seeing you are getting the form when a post requires password.